# What are circular symlinks in Unix-like systems used for?

Tags: linux, symlink

I was browsing a directory on a Linux machine, and when doing a detailed listing I noticed that a link is pointing to itself, for example:

```
somelink -> /path/to/directory/somelink
```

I am wondering what is the reason for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `somelink` is in `/path/to/directory` then this is an invalid symlink. If you try to access it, the filesystem will give you an error (probably something like *too many levels of symbolic links**). It could have been a typo (or some other mistake) when it was created, or the symlink got moved somehow and ended up linking to itself.

Answer (score 4):

There's no good reason for a circular symlink.  Most probably, it was created by accident.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the answer

Comment: @A.B There *is* a good reason to have a circular symlink. See may answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37403156/4358570).